# How to send data from android mobile to android tv securely?

Tags: android, encryption, android-tv, google-nearby

I have this android mobile app which is a client of an NVR software. It uses basic auth and api key for server authentication. I am now building an app for android tv. I'm adding a feature which allows authentication using mobile. For this, I am using [Nearby](https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/android/discover-devices) library from google where the TV becomes the advertiser and the mobile becomes the discoverer. I am able to send data (credentials) from mobile to tv with no issues. However, I would like to secure the data. I thought of securing the data using encryption and have read [this](https://mkyong.com/java/java-aes-encryption-and-decryption/) and [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20120318012218/http://www.tutorials-android.com/learn/How_to_encrypt_and_decrypt_strings.rhtml) but having issues like "javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: data too short" or "javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted". I think the issue is because I am using a short string (6 characters) for the secret key.

What I'm doing is I let the tv generate a random 6 digit code and shows it at the screen. Now on the mobile app, I ask the user to enter the 6 digit code. I then use this code to encrypt the credentials. When the TV receives the data, I need to decrypt it using the same digit code.

Here's my code for the encrypt and decrypt. It's not working at the moment.

```
public class DoCrypto {

    private static final String ENCRYPT_ALGO = "AES/GCM/NoPadding";
    private static final int TAG_LENGTH_BIT = 128;
    private static final int IV_LENGTH_BYTE = 12;
    private static final int AES_KEY_BIT = 256;

    private static final Charset UTF_8 = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

    public static String encrypt(String clearText, String code) throws Exception {

        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(code.toCharArray(), code.getBytes(UTF_8), 1000, 256);
        SecretKey secretKey = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1").generateSecret(keySpec);
        return new String(encrypt(clearText.getBytes(), secretKey));

    }

    public static String decrypt(String encryptedText, String code) throws Exception {

        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(code.toCharArray(), code.getBytes(UTF_8), 1000, 256);
        SecretKey secretKey = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1").generateSecret(keySpec);
        return decrypt(encryptedText.getBytes(), secretKey);
    }

    public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] pText, SecretKey secret) throws Exception {

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ENCRYPT_ALGO);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
        byte[] encryptedText = cipher.doFinal(pText);
        return encryptedText;

    }

    public static String decrypt(byte[] cText, SecretKey secret) throws Exception {

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ENCRYPT_ALGO);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret);
        byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(cText);
        return new String(plainText, UTF_8);

    }

}
```

I am testing this by

```
    try {
        String code = DoCrypto.encrypt("Clear Text","1234");
        Log.d("crypt", code);
        Log.d("crypt", DoCrypto.decrypt(code, "1234"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This code gives me the error "javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: data too short" mentioned above. So maybe I'm thinking I might not be doing this correctly since I only use a 4-6 digit secret key.

Are there better ways to secure the data?

UPDATE #1:

After some tinkering, I'm now getting the error "javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: mac check in GCM failed". Currently googling this now to know the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Nearby Connections provides both devices with an auth token (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/connection/ConnectionInfo#getAuthenticationToken()). As long as you confirm it before sending sensitive data, the actual connection and data transfer will be secure.

Most clients simply show the token on both screens and have a confirmation step. Some hash it (into a number, or into a series of images) to make it a little more friendly to read.